# How to map a macro over a list - or - How to use macros to define data types

Tags: macros, scheme, read-eval-print-loop, r5rs

I like to build a REPL with my own datatypes, but I don't like to write all the same pattern functions over and over again.

So this is a nut, which bothers me.

I got my own set of primitive datatypes `(define primitives '("mytrue" "myfalse" "mynumber" ...))`

Also I have `(define primitiveTesters (list "mytrue?" "myfalse?" "mynumber?" ... )`

The problem now is, I just want to apply (map) or a macro to get the datatype? procedurces, which basically just checks if the car of record `(mynumber . ( . ))` exists.

So something similar like `(mynumber? (car (mynumber.(1.))) => #t` in the end. But for this I need `(define mynumber? (lambda (...)(...))`

My define-batching macro looks like this, but I just have no luck to infuse the `<variable>`.

```
(define-syntax define-batching
(syntax-rules () 
((_ value expr)(define value expr))
((_ value) value)
((_ value1 value2 ...)  (begin (define value1 expr) (define-batching test2...)))
))
```

So have I reached a dead end of scheme ?

I've seen something similar, I think in Emacs Lisp.

What I am looking for in the end is:

```
 (define checker '(audi? volkswagen? mercedes?))
 (define datatype '(audi volkswagen mercedes))

 (map define-checker checker datatype )
 or
 (define-checker (car checker) (car datatype))
```

Comment: With respect to (map define-checker checker datatype ) you can't map macros over a list. In (define-checker (car checker) (car datatype)) assuming define-checker is a macro the expansion happens at *compile-time* there fore checker hasn't got a value yet. That happens at *run-time*. If you need to have list values at compile time (as opposed to syntax-objects, then you need to look at more advanced macro systems. But see addendum to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question right, you need a macro
to define your own type checkers?

Here is one way to do it:

```
(define-syntax define-checker
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(define-checker name tag)
     (define (name object)
       (and (list? object)
            (not (null? object))
            (eq? (car object) 'tag)))]))

(define-checker my-car? car)

(my-car? '(car audi black))   ; evaluates to #t
(my-car? '(truck ford pink))  ; evaluates to #f
```

Addendum:

If you write

```
(define checker '(audi? volkswagen? mercedes?))
(define datatype '(audi volkswagen mercedes))
```

the values will become available at runtime.
Therefore you need to a different approach.

You could for example write:

```
(define-checker+datatype (audi? audi) (volkswagen? volkswagen?))
```

Here is the code:

```
(define-syntax define-checker
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(define-checker name tag)
     (define (name object)
       (and (list? object)
            (not (null? object))
            (eq? (car object) 'tag)))]))


(define-syntax define-checkers+datatype
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(define-checkers+datatype (name tag) ...)
     (begin
       (define-checker name tag)
       ...)]))

(define-checkers+datatype (audi? audi) (wv? wv))


(audi? '(audi black))
```

Comment: Ok, I see. 

Great alternative you offer.  Tks a lot for the support.

Answer (score 0):

`define-syntax` is hygienic, that means it cannot influence on parent environment, that means it cannot define symbols in it.
You may try to use er-, ir- macro-transformers which allow you to explicit renames symbols.

keywords to google in you scheme documentation are 'er-macro-transformet' and 'ir-macro-transformer'

Comment: Regarding `syntax-rules`; there is nothing wrong with `define` inside a macro, specifically in this case, the `value` identifier is passed in by the user, so the definition will be visible.

Comment: `syntax-rules` is hygienic, but `syntax-case` transformer can create unhygienic macros.you can introduce new symbols to break the hygien with `datum->syntax` .